# using slf4j to log in spring when I can't get rid of commons-logging

Tags: spring, slf4j

I'm using some a component other than Spring that has a commons-logging dependency.

So, excluding commons-logging from the spring dependency doesn't get rid of it, and so the instructions [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/overview.html) aren't helping. Is there some more declarative way to push Spring 3.0.5 to talk to slf4j?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Maven, please read the FAQ entry about [excluding commons-logging](http://slf4j.org/faq.html#excludingJCL).

Answer (score 2):

I had an issue on Tomcat 6 where Commons Logging wouldn't play nice with SLF4J which got dragged in from Hibernate.  We had configured Commons Logging to go to Log4J anyway.  After explicitly including "slf4j-log4j 1.6.1" and its "jcl-over-slf4j 1.6.1" component to take out Commons Logging, I still got errors from Commons Logging.  The answer lied in [this blog post](http://day-to-day-stuff.blogspot.com/2007/07/no-more-commons-logging.html): You explicitly include Commons Logging at version "99.0-does-not-exist".  This includes an empty JAR, so that only the SLF4J code gets executed now.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [SLF4j bridge](http://www.slf4j.org/legacy.html)

Comment: Nope. If you read the page, it says that you have to get commons-logging out of the classpath for that to work. My original problem was the presence of components that drag it back in.